# Genesis 27:25, "of my Son's game" or "of your game"?

Tags: genesis, exodus, hebrew-bible

The matter here in Genesis 27:25 is like that of Exodus 33:19 (the two LORDs). [Look here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/exodus-3319-how-the-lord-will-proclaim-the-name-of-the-lord) .

Genesis 27:25 (ESV):

> Then he said, “Bring it near to me, that **I may eat of my son’s game and bless you.**” So he brought it near to him, and he ate; and he brought him wine, and he drank.

There are many sites in the Bible have the same problem.

This problem constitute a phenomenon in the Holy Quran. The interpreters of the Holy Quran call it التفات, التفات=switch.

There are about 1000 verses in the Holy Quran have this phenomenon of total 6236 verse.

For me, it constitutes no problem at all. For me it opens our eyes on more and more Exegetical and Hermeneutical approaches, using Dialectic.

Is it "eat of my Son's game (hunting)" or "eat of your game"?

In this verse the Revelation switched from pronoun (your) to noun (my Son's). It switched from second person (your) to third person (my Son's=his).

The phenomenon of الإلتفات=Switch, needs more study.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ESV is a good translation that reflects the underlying Hebrew well.  Here is the NASB which as a very similar translation:

> So he said, "Bring it to me, and I will eat of my son's game, that I
>   may bless you." And he brought it to him, and he ate; he also brought
>   him wine and he drank.

The operative word here is בְּנִ֔י (bə·nî), Noun - masculine singular construct, first person common singular, which is clearly "my son's" in this sentence.  The word is from the root word בֵּן (ben) which means "son" or descendant.

I will not comment on the Arabic and the Quran as we are discussing the Hebrew of the Bible here.

Comment: +1, are you going  to expand  your  answer?  I hope  so.

Comment: In what way do you want it expanded?

Comment: to add more  details, like your  point of view, like this phenomenon (Switch) in the Bible and as such. To get best answer.

Comment: I do not understand the "switch" you discuss and am not familiar with such as far as the Bible literature is concerned.  The narrative in Gen 27 is a very simple, uncomplicated narrative and is not mystical.

Comment: switch is  like  turning  around,  for example: when we should  use singular,  we find The text uses plural or vice versa.  The same with pronouns, and so on.

Comment: OK, but I do not see this in the text of Gen 27.

Comment: instead of "your" He used "my son", Switching from  pronoun to noun, Switching  from speech pronoun  to absence  pronoun.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107430/discussion-between-dottard-and-salah).